# Python: Saber si un elemento de una lista está en una cadena de texto

Tags: python, condiciones, arraylist

```
palabras = ["hola","que tal","buenos días"]
frase1 = "buenos días, me llamo rogelio"
frase2 = "me llamo rogelio"

if palabras in frase1:
    print("Sí ha saludado")
else:
    print("No ha saludado") 

if palabras in frase2:
    print("Sí ha saludado")
else:
    print("No ha saludado")
```

Lo que quiero comprobar es que si alguna de las palabras en la lista está en una cadena de texto, por favor pido ayuda.

Comment: `any(word in frase1 for word in palabras)`

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es:

```
def algunaPalabra(palabras, frase):
    for p in palabras:
        if p in frase:
            return True

    return False
```

Y si quieres que las palabras deban estar completas:

```
def algunaPalabra(palabras, frase):
    palabrasEnFrase = frase.split(" ")
    for p in palabras:
        if p in palabrasEnFrase:
            return True

    return False
```

Se trata de dos funciones que esperan que el parámetro `palabras` sea una lista o tupla. Decidí hacer funciones porque puedes cortar el ciclo antes devolviendo un valor.

En ambos casos se verifican las palabras una a una con el operador `in`. Si encuentra una, devuelve `True` y sino `False`.